# Getting 403 Forbidden with Nginx/Rails/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, passenger

I inherited a Rails/Passenger/Nignx app that returns a 403 error when attempting to view the site in the browser. The logs give me some variation of this error:

```
2019/12/05 20:45:47 [error] 22624#22624: *1 directory index of "/home/deploy/my_app/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 123.456.789.51, server: sub.mydomain.org, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "sub.mydomain.org"
2
```

The `*1` may be `5` or any other number it seems.

My troubleshooting leads me to believe it's an issue with Passenger not actually running. When I run `sudo /usr/sbin/passenger-memory-stats` I get no active Passenger processes (and two Nginx processes). Searching makes me to believe I'm getting the 403 because Passenger isn't actually serving up the Rails app.

I've verified that Passenger is enabled and has a root set (and verified that the .ini file and ruby exists at those locations). This feels like a configuration issue but I'm not sure what else to check.

EDIT:
Turns there is a command to see if Passenger is running, `passenger-status`. I get

```
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it is running, then the causes of this problem could be
```

Running `passenger-config validate-install` returns `Everything looks good. :-)`

Here are the relevant configuration files:

#### nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
#include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6"

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##
    
    include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

#### passenger.conf

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

#### default.conf (picked up through sites-enabled)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 default deferred;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
  root /home/deploy/my_app/current/public;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/sub.mydomain.org.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 5s;

  ssl_ciphers REDACTED

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
  add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";

  # root /home/deployer/dukemyq-be/public;

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }
  error_page 503 @maintenance;
  location @maintenance {
    rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html last;
    break;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

#  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
#  location @unicorn {
#    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
#    proxy_redirect off;
#    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
#  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }
  error_page 503 @maintenance;
  location @maintenance {
    rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html last;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no experience with Rails but `403 Forbidden` is a general `Nginx` error message that not necessarily means there is an access rights issue. There can be an issue with your app (or SSL). Do you have an `index.html` file in your `public` folder? Otherwise it may be trying to index your `public` folder while indexing is probably disabled. I would backup your config file and make a new one which is as small/minimal as possible. What the `Nginx` error log is saying? Did you look at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?

Comment: Also restart the service with `sudo service nginx restart` and look at the access log: `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

Comment: Hello, did you fix this issue?